# php array: loop through multidimensional array from api

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to loop through a multidimensional array. I did it several times before, but this API call drives me nuts. Maybe I should stop coding after 10 hours. :/

My goal is to extract the US age certification **where note=""** from this call. The variable is called `$movie`

```
$url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" . $movieID . "?api_key=" . $apiKey . "&" . $language . "&" . $sortBy . "&append_to_response=release_dates"; // path to your JSON file
$data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
$movie = json_decode($data); // decode the JSON feed
```

foreach:

```
foreach ($movie->release_dates as $result) {
    echo $result->release_dates;
}
```

delivers:

```
array(31) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#12 (2) {
    ["iso_3166_1"]=>
    string(2) "FR"
    ["release_dates"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#13 (5) {
        ["certification"]=>
        string(1) "U"
        ["iso_639_1"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["note"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["release_date"]=>
        string(24) "2018-02-07T00:00:00.000Z"
        ["type"]=>
        int(3)
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#14 (2) {
    ["iso_3166_1"]=>
    string(2) "US"
    ["release_dates"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#15 (5) {
        ["certification"]=>
        string(5) "PG-13"
        ["iso_639_1"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["note"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["release_date"]=>
        string(24) "2018-01-26T00:00:00.000Z"
        ["type"]=>
        int(3)
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#16 (5) {
        ["certification"]=>
        string(5) "PG-13"
        ["iso_639_1"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["note"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["release_date"]=>
        string(24) "2018-04-24T00:00:00.000Z"
        ["type"]=>
        int(5)
      }
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#17 (2) {
    ["iso_3166_1"]=>
    string(2) "CA"
    ["release_dates"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#18 (5) {
        ["certification"]=>
        string(2) "PG"
        ["iso_639_1"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["note"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["release_date"]=>
        string(24) "2018-01-26T00:00:00.000Z"
        ["type"]=>
        int(3)
      }
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#19 (2) {
    ["iso_3166_1"]=>
    string(2) "LT"
    ["release_dates"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#20 (5) {
        ["certification"]=>
        string(4) "N-13"
        ["iso_639_1"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["note"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["release_date"]=>
        string(24) "2018-01-26T00:00:00.000Z"
        ["type"]=>
        int(3)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I do not know how to proceed. In this case it should be an R-rating.

Comment: Share some code of how you trying to do that

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
$data = '
[
    {
        "iso" : "FR",
        "dates" : [
            {
                "note": "",
                "date": "06.09.2020"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "iso" : "US",
        "dates" : [
            {
                "note": "",
                "date": "06.09.2020"
            },
            {
                "note": "",
                "date": "07.09.2020"
            },
            {
                "note": "not empty",
                "date": "08.09.2020"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "iso" : "US",
        "dates" : [
            {
                "note": "not empty",
                "date": "09.09.2020"
            },
            {
                "note": "",
                "date": "10.09.2020"
            },
            {
                "note": "not empty",
                "date": "11.09.2020"
            }
        ]
    }
]';

// use json_decode with true to get a associative array.
$movies = json_decode($data, true);
$dates  = array();

foreach ($movies as $movie) {
    
    if ($movie['iso'] === 'US' && isset($movie['dates']) && is_array($movie['dates'])) {
        
        foreach ($movie['dates'] as $date) {
            
            if (isset($date['note']) && empty($date['note']) && isset($date['date']) && $date['date']) {
                
                $dates[] = $date['date'];
            }
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($dates);
echo '</pre>';
```

And as response:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 06.09.2020
    [1] => 07.09.2020
    [2] => 10.09.2020
)
```

Comment: thank you. but it is not working. seems to be a problem with the mix of arrays and objects.

Comment: still not working. `var_dump($result);`is NULL. as far as I can see the provided code looks great. I do not know why it does not work.

Comment: If that is what you get after json parsing (meaning your example) it should works, check if you use the right key names to getting the nested arrays and values you need.